# jQuery - call function on resize AND after clicking a button

Tags: jquery

I want to call a function only **If the window size `< 767` (should work with resizing) AND after clicking a button**

This code I have works perfectly if I make the window size `< 767` and click search. BUT, it doesnt work if I click the button on window size `> 767` and `RESIZE` to `< 767`. I'm looking for a way to combine all `<767` and `resize` and button click?

This is what I have so far. Can you guys please help?

```
function searchButtonClick(){

    if(jQuery(window).width() < 767){
        jQuery('.search_mob').slideUp(500);
        jQuery('.carousel-wrapper').hide(); //show search function
        jQuery('.innerSearhPopup').slideUp(300); //show search function

        if (jQuery('.carousel-wrapper').css('display') == 'none')
            {
               jQuery('.innerSearhPopup').css({'top':'109px' });
            }

        }
}
```

Comment: Consider using CSS with media queries instead.

Comment: Cant. Because there are more conditions around this function. Like checking homepage or not, etc etc

Comment: You can turn those conditions into CSS classes managed by jQuery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add an event handler for the window resize:

```
jQuery(window).resize(searchButtonClick);
```

**Edit**
If you only want to do this once the button has been clicked at least once, you can attach the handler after the first click:

```
// keep track of whether you have attached the handler
var isattached = false;                
function searchButtonClick(){
    // attach the handler if it hasn't been added yet
    if (!isattached){                  
        isattached = true;
        jQuery(window).resize(searchButtonClick);
    }

    if(jQuery(window).width() < 767){
        jQuery('.search_mob').slideUp(500);
        jQuery('.carousel-wrapper').hide(); //show search function
        jQuery('.innerSearhPopup').slideUp(300); //show search function

        if (jQuery('.carousel-wrapper').css('display') == 'none')
            {
               jQuery('.innerSearhPopup').css({'top':'109px' });
            }

        }
}
```

Comment: But this doesnt trigger on button click if I put it outside the function. This will trigger everytime I resize the window.

Comment: You need an event handler for your button click AND the window resize. That way, the function will be called when the window resizes or when the button gets clicked. Or do you only want to execute the code once the button has been clicked?

Comment: Thanks Kenneth. I want to execute the code once the button has been clicked only.

Comment: Thank you Thank you Thank you!! I spent hours trying to figure this out. Do you think this is possible with media queries? Just asking.

Comment: Yes definitely, this is possible with media queries. (except for the animation). Just create a mediaquery with specific classes inside it. Once the button is clicked, add those classes to your HTML dynamically through jQuery